# Django 1.6 + AngularJS v1.2.6 + Amazon Aws

Tags: django, angularjs, amazon-web-services, static, amazon-s3

I have a problem integrating my existing django app with angular, I have setted Amazon AWS with Boto for the static files, but when using AngularJs i get this error:

`Blocked loading resource from url not allowed by $sceDelegate policy.  URL:`

So I investigated and tried to do this:

```
$sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist(['self',djangoStaticURL]);
```

On my module config but dopesn't seem to work, so I tried:

```
templateUrl: $sceProvider.trustAsResourceUrl(djangoStaticURL + 'app/views/main.html'),
```

And get $sce provider not defined, this is my complete module:

```
angular.module('portfolioApp', [
  'ngCookies',
  'ngResource',
  'ngSanitize',
  'ngRoute',
  'portfolioApp.filters',
]).config(function ($sce ,$routeProvider, $sceDelegateProvider) {
  $sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist(['self',djangoStaticURL]);
  $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
      templateUrl: $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(djangoStaticURL + 'app/views/main.html'),
      //templateUrl: djangoStaticURL + 'app/views/main.html',
      controller: 'MainCtrl'
    })
    .otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/'
    });
});
```

So is this a bad idea ? should I do all the routing from django ? or is there something I-m missing?

Comment: @Brendan Actually yes, check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally solved this by editing AWS CORS configuration like this:

Select your bucket where your static files are
Select Properties
Select Edit CORS configuration

Paste something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>http://arlefreak.herokuapp.com/</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>http://*.arlefreak.com/</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

More info at: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html